# How do I exclude consecutive RelationshipTypes in a neo4j java traversal?

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal

I need to select nodes from a neo4j graphdb based on ordered paths.

I need paths with the following constraints:

1) A path may follow types C, D, and outgoing M

2) a type C must never follow a type C or type M

3) a type D must never follow type D or type M

How do I write an java evaluator for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the evaluator I eventually used, where IS_MEMBER is the relationship M described in the question.

```
public Evaluation evaluate(final Path path) {
    if (path.length() == 0) {
        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
    }
    boolean isOutgoingIS_MEMBER = (
        path.lastRelationship().getEndNode() == 
        path.endNode() &&
        (path.lastRelationship()
    .isType(ReqsDb.RelTypes.IS_MEMBER)));
    boolean isRelTypeUnique = true;
    Iterator<Relationship> i = 
        path.reverseRelationships().iterator();
    i.next();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        if (i.next().isType(path.lastRelationship()
                .getType())) {
            isRelTypeUnique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    boolean included = isOutgoingIS_MEMBER || isRelTypeUnique;
    boolean continued = included;
    return Evaluation.of(included, continued);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PathExpander and optionally (for performance) the BranchState to keep state about where each branch is a.t.m. instead of looking at the path in each evaluation